# creating a new dataframe based on a column storing index

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on using ALS on pyspark to do collaborative filtering. The models is giving prediction results in a dataframe like below.

```
CustomerID    ProductID    Rating
    0             4          4.2
    0             2          2.7
    0             6           3
    1             7          2.3
    1             0          0.5
    2             3          3.1
```

I want to transform the dataframe into a user to item matrix like below where the productID becomes column and each row represent one user's rating on all products.

```
0    0    2.7  0    4.2  0    3    0
0.5  0    0    0    0    0    0    2.3
0    0    0    3.1  0    0    0    0
```

So for this dataframe R, R[0,2]=2.7 means user 0 gives rating 2.7 to product 2. R[2,3] = 3.1 means user 2 gives product 3 a score of 3.1.

Is there anyway to do it in pyspark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the [pivot](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot) function followed by an aggregation function. I decided to use [max](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.max) but depending on your data other functions like [avg](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.avg) could be used.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import max

l = [( 0,             4.0 ,         4.2),
    (0,             2.0,         2.7),
    (0,             6.0,           3.0),
    (1,             7.0,          2.3),
    (1,             0.0,          0.5),
    (2,             3.0,          3.1)]

columns = ['CustomerID',    'ProductID',    'Rating']

df=spark.createDataFrame(l, columns)
df = df.groupby('CustomerID').pivot('ProductID').agg(max("Rating"))
df.show()
```

Output:

```py
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+ 
|CustomerID| 0.0| 2.0| 3.0| 4.0| 6.0| 7.0| 
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+ 
|         0|null| 2.7|null| 4.2| 3.0|null| 
|         1| 0.5|null|null|null|null| 2.3| 
|         2|null|null| 3.1|null|null|null| 
+----------+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```